# AutoMapper Inherit Profile Maps

Tags: c#, automapper

```
public class ProfileA : ProfileB
{
    CreateMap<Source, Destination>(d => d.Age, opt => opt.UseValue(14));
}

public class ProfileB : Profile
{
    public ProfileB()
    {
        CreateMap<Source, Destination>(d => d.Name, opt => opt.UseValue("qqq"));
    }
}
```

Even though the maps are on same source and destination type I want the separation by creating a base Profile then inheriting and creating more specific Profiles. But as with above code only `ProfileA`'s mappers will be applied.

How can I achieve such feat using AutoMapper or is it even considered a good practice for AutoMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same map in different profiles is an anti-pattern and is not allowed by default. There is only one map and overriding it in this way only makes things difficult. See [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2353). It can be [overridden](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration#allow-additive-type-map-creation).